# Should there be a comma after "throughout this paper''?

Tags: commas, dependent-clause

Throughout this paper G is assumed to be simple graph.

or

Throughout this paper, G is assumed to be simple graph.

Comment: why this question got a downvote?

Comment: Ah, you've been hit by a driveby downvoter, a plague upon this site.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, @rational, but I'd assume it's because your question appears to be a request for proofreading which is off-topic for the site.  If you include your rationale for having doubt as to whether there should be a comma or not, the question might be considered salvageable but the way it is presented currently, it's off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Punctuation is a matter of style, and you're best guided by your manual of style, either the one you've adopted or the one thrust upon you.  These manuals differ in many respects, but most will recommend that a comma follow a suitably-long introductory adverbial phrase.  Does "throughout this paper" qualify?  As I said, it's a matter of style.

I would recommend the comma, since it avoids misleading your readers into an incorrect parse path with "G" as an appositive of "paper":  "Figure D," "Lemma E," "Theorem F," "paper G."  The last is impossible, and your readers will figure that out from context, but the comma after "paper" will insure they don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

First things first :

```
 This paper will assume that G is simple graph.
```

I don't know your math background, but if we say that G is simple graph usually we prove it using the the definition of simple graph and yeah we don't assume we define and prove beforehand. We use the definition to the terms we are using in papers.

Comment: I don't know who "we" is, but the OP's statement (and your restatement) are notational, alerting the reader to the fact that the name "G" refers to a simple graph.  There's no need to prove that G is simple; it's a definition on which proofs about simple graphs will be made.

Comment: Speaking of math notations : he haven't defined the sets of vertices and edges therefore he haven't defined the graph at all. G(V,E) -http://www.or.uni-bonn.de/~hougardy/paper/girthall.pdf . The graph already exists, so he should prove it is simple before he states it as obvious.

Comment: The context is missing so it's not possible to be sure, but the statement probably isn't about a graph; it's about the name of a graph.  For instance, "This paper will assume that G is a simple graph.  If |V|>=11, then either G or its complement is nonplanar"  "G" is just the name of a simple graph.  The simplicity of G is not proved; it's assumed for purposes of proving things in the paper.